# Navigate to AngularJS's SPA with QueryString parameters

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angular-routing

The link to my SPA is constructed of an absolute URL + Query-String parameter as the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Pepole/Index?personId=[some_ID]
```

And my route configuration is:

```
tmc.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/People/Person', controller: peopleController });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

Given my config, when routing to `/`, how can I retain the `personId` parameter so it would be available in the respective controller (`peopleController`) and I will be able to access it.

Comment: Why are you redirecting? Won't you lose bookmarkability?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I'll lose, but this is a constraint right now, I need to arrive my SPA through another location. any idea?

Comment: Why do you need it to redirect? Why not just keep it on the path entered?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller what do you mean by: _keep it on the path entered_?

Comment: You're redirecting from "/People/Index" to "/". If the user lands on your app at "/People/Index", why can't they stay there? The two routes can share the same controller and template, if need be.

Answer (score 0):

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location#search](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#search)

> ### search(search, paramValue)
>
> This method is getter / setter.
>
> Return search part (as object) of current url when called without any parameter.
>
> Change search part when called with parameter and return `$location`.
>
> *Parameters*
>   `search(optional)` – `{string|object<string,string>=}` – New search params - string or hash object
>   `paramValue(optional)` – `{string=}` – If `search` is a string, then `paramValue` will override  only a single search parameter. If the value is `null`, the parameter will be deleted.
>   *Returns*
>   `{string} – search`

```
function SomeCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.personId = $location.search().personId;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inject $routeParams in your controller and then simply call $routeParams.yourQueryParameter.

For example:

```
function SomeCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.personId = $routeParams.personId;
}
```